# How much do radiation-resistant suits cost?

Tags: radiation, radioactivity

Let's say you wanted a top-of-the-line, impenetrable suit to withstand high levels of radiation.  How much does one of these suits cost?

Comment: There is a (low) limit to how much shielding you can more around wearing. There isn't any such beast. Suits are not used to resist *radiation* (by which I mean to prevent you from being affected by the a beta/gamma field) they are used to isolate the wearer from inhaling active material, or carrying such material into clean spaces where it represents a threat to the health of others.

Comment: Now, if you are worried about $\alpha$ exposure it’s easy. Otherwise @dmckee is right on...

Comment: I'm wearing a suit right now that stops 100% of alpha and beta radiation, and so are you.

Comment: @BenCrowell I certainly am not. Skin is sufficient to stop low energy beta radiation, but very much insufficient for higher end energies. The beta radiation from Phosphorous-32, for instance, is $500~\rm keV$ on average, which is enough to penetrate around $2~\rm cm$ of skin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- RST Demron® [Full Body Suit](https://www.radshield.com/product/demron-full-body-suit/) - U$2K.

> [Demron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demron) is a radiation-shielding fabric. Weight-for-weight the material has slightly lower radiation protection than lead shielding, however being flexible. It is essentially particles of metal embedded in a polyethylene-based material.

Usage of the suit is combined with portable shielding and self contained breathing apparatus.

Image from [FireEngineering.com](https://www.fireengineering.com/articles/2011/06/demron--protects-against.html):

[image: Suit and Shield]

> Miami, FL ([PRWEB](https://www.prweb.com/releases/2008/02/prweb724423.htm)) February 27, 2008 - "NATO Funds Record Purchase of New Demron Nuclear Radiation-Blocking, Anti-Chemical and Biological-Protection Suits":
>
> Ronald DeMeo, MD, MBA, president and chief executive officer with Radiation Shield Technologies (RST), today announced NATO's funding of a purchase of a **record number** of Demron nuclear radiation-blocking, anti-chemical and biological-protection suits. The suits, which will be deployed by the Ministry for Emergency Situations of the Republic of Belarus, are manufactured with RST's patented Demron technology, the first and only product of its kind.

> Miami, FL ([PRWEB](https://www.prweb.com/releases/2007/11/prweb572317.htm)) November 27, 2007 - "World’s First Nuclear Radiation-Blocking Fabric Receives New Patents":
>
> "Demron is a liquid metal that feels like fabric and is cool to the touch,” said DeMeo, the surgeon who developed Demron. “It’s **the world’s only full-body radiation protection fabric that shields against X-ray and low-energy Gamma emissions** while providing full anti-chemical and biological protection. Demron is a lead-free, toxin-free, and PVC-free nuclear-blocking material that allows heat dissipation and resists chemical permeation and cracks.”
>
> Numerous universities and government laboratories have confirmed Demron’s ability to block radiation. Demron has several U.S. patents.

> MIAMI--([Business Wire](https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20111215006556/en/Radiation-Shield-Technologies%E2%80%99-RST-Demron-W-Suit-Receives))--Radiation Shield Technologies (RST) today announced its patented Demron-W CBRN Class 2 suit received two key certifications that further solidify its market leadership as the only full-body suit providing anti-nuclear and multi-hazard protection from chemical, biological, radiological and nuclear agents. The suit, made with the Demron technology **currently used in the nuclear radiation cleanups following the Fukushima Nuclear Disaster**, is noted by governments and first responder organizations worldwide for its unique life-saving benefits.

Comment: *Weight-for-weight* is worth noting.

Comment: From the ad copy at the other end of the first link: *"at least 50% shielding of gamma rays up to 130 Kev."* ::chuckles::  Oh my. Well, well, well. That will help *ever* so much. As I said above (and as the rest of the text implicitly acknowledges) the main purpose is to prevent the user from inhaling or ingesting activated material.

Comment: Is there a better suit, how much does it cost - that will be a better answer than this one.

Comment: @Rob The real answer (as alluded to in dmckee's comment) is there is no such thing as an effective radiation-shielding suit. Effectively shielding a person-sized enclosure can easily be literal tons of lead, so any suit is going to fall far short.

Comment: I've improved the answer with creditable references. @Chris, it's much like saying bomb disposal suits and bullet proof vests aren't effective against everything - so we ought to view their effectiveness with skepticism. The suit is sufficiently effective to be worn at Fukushima - that does not imply that ***I*** am keen to don this suit and wander around in the facility. The OP nine-hundred asked "... top-of-the-line ... how much?", that is what I answered, not whether or not nuclear (or asbestos) disposal is our career of choice.

Comment: Yes, it is made to keep radiation as low as reasonably achievable for people that need to be in high radiation zones, and, much more critically, preventing contamination. It's significantly better than nothing (thus why they use it), but the suit alone does not block much- I certainly wouldn't call it an "impenetrable suit to withstand high levels of radiation."

Answer (score 1):

The industry standard is keep one's distance while any prompt radiation dies away, and to use a disposable, impenetrable suit to avoid having contaminated particles stick to you.

I've done some work where I had to wear a Tyvek suit, which seems to be available on Amazon for less than \$10 each. The respirator (which gets reused) is a more substantial investment.